# Changing font size of a region or single characters

Tags: fonts, text-properties

Is it possible in Emacs to change the font size of a single character or region, without affecting the whole Emacs window?

Comment: In Elisp programs `(add-face-text-property (region-beginning) (region-end) '(:height 200))` does the trick. Replace 200 with the number of your choice. This only works for buffers without font-lock. If font-lock is active you need to add the `:size` face attribute via `font-lock-add-keywords`.

Comment: @tobias: Please consider posting your comment as an answer. Thx.

Comment: @Drew Hi, I was not sure whether the OP wanted an Elisp solution or an interactive one. But, you are right. If that is not what the OP wants one can just add another answer or extent that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Elisp programs the following form does the trick for the text in the current region.

```el
 (add-face-text-property (region-beginning) (region-end) '(:height 200))
```

Replace 200 with the number of your choice.

This only works for buffers without font-lock. If font-lock is active you need to add the `:size` face attribute via `font-lock-add-keywords`.

Comment: Evaluating the function above doesn't change anything. How should it be used?

Comment: @amirteymuri Please try it in `text-mode` or `fundamental-mode` with an active region. Afterwards switch to your actual target buffer and look what the value of `font-lock-mode` is. You can do that through direct evaluation by `M-: font-lock-mode` or by the help `C-h v font-lock-mode`. As I already stated in the answer that method does not work for buffers with `font-lock-mode` enabled. If you have such a buffer you  must more comprehensively describe what you want to achieve: Do you want to change the font size for some syntactical thing or is it a one-time change of a user-selected region?